# Extracting Metadata of a GeoTiff image

Tags: qgis, r, metadata, landsat-8, land-classification

I am working on Landsat 8 satellite image and want to perform land cover classification for a particular region
Preferred software tool is R
I have formed a RGB image from the satellite data and now want to extract the metadata of that image to work further on it

How can the metadata be extracted?
Can it be done in R or should I use QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS, Right-click the layer you are visualizing > Click on Properties > Click on the blue i symbol (which stands for Metadata)

In R:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)

#Create a raster layer and view the same
layer <- raster("path to folder where image is stored")
writeRaster(layer,"path to where want to write it to", format="ascii")

###Convert the ascii to dataframe
layer1 <- asc2dataframe("path where the ascii is stored")
```

Above should give you values for each row.

Comment: Thanks for response Vijay!! Using the above R code we get basic information such as nrow, ncol, cells, extent,names etc. Now I am interested in knowing the data behind the cells ( I.e behind each row and column), which I believe will help me in further classify/cluster the data. More like forming a database.

Comment: Edited to reflect the same.

Comment: @G.D. Let me know if that helps?

Comment: Thanks Vijay, unfortunately haven't given the above code a shot yet!! Will let you know once I execute!! Appreciate your help

Comment: thank you for the help..It worked.. Just for my understanding, we need to look at the "var.1" variable as values, with x and y being the coordinates.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Do mark the question as completed if it answers your query.

Comment: Hi Vijay, I would like to know if its possible to perform the same exercise for Multispectral Image i.e. combination of RGB and extract the metadata for the same.

Comment: Hi @G.D.. That is definitely possible. One can use a combination of code from the raster package and RSToolbox to do the same. Why don't you post it as a separate question and tage me or , I would suggest checking the getValues function from the raster package (for a raster stack of R, G and B), and potentially using ggRGB, if you want to plot them (using RSToolBox).

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS select Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Information ...

[image]

The same can be achieve in console:

```
gdalinfo <path to geotiff>
```